# Jquery não executa em conteúdo carregado com a função .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu estou tentando carregar uma página usando a função Jquery .load(), eu uso um modal para exibir o conteúdo na página principal, o problema é que dentro do modal tem algumas funções que dependem do jQuery (máscara de input, Jquery DatePicker e outros), e não executam de forma alguma. Nenhum erro é mostrado no console.

Segue um exemplo que fiz no codepen, para tentar exemplificar o problema, se observarem o botão de fechar não funciona, e nem popover que tem no body da modal.

Arquivo Principal`https://codepen.io/laercionunesc/pen/NYBKpw/`
Arquivo chamado pelo .load() `https://codepen.io/laercionunesc/pen/jzpNwx`

Estou a disposição para mais esclarecimentos sobre o problema.

Comment: Você tem que chamar as funções para ativação de máscara, entre outras após o load.

Comment: Considere adicionar os trechos de código relevantes em sua própria pergunta, o editor possui a opção para inserir código...perguntas com códigos hospedados em outros serviços tendem a não receber muita atenção, inevitavelmente ficam sem respostas ou ganham "downvotes"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precisa usar `e.stopPropagation();` e um *callback* após o `.load`. Notei também que o `.popover` só funciona após o segundo click, por isso adicionei um `.trigger`.

**Exemplo:**

```js
$('.editar').on('click', function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
   var $this = $(this);
   var remote = $this.data('load-remote');
   console.log(remote);
   $('#exampleModal').load( remote, function(){
      $(this).modal();

      $('.popover-test').on('click', function(){
         $('.popover-test').popover({
            container: 'body'
         });
      }).trigger('click');
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<h1>Modal com .load()</h1>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary editar" data-toggle="modal" data-load-remote="https://codepen.io/laercionunesc/pen/jzpNwx.html" data-target="#exampleModal">Open modal</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
</div>
```

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado!!! Sua resposta foi útil e me deu base para conseguir resolver.